# Update data from List1 to List2 in SharePoint List

Tags: list, sharepoint-foundation, sharepoint-online

I've two Lists, List1 and List2.

I want to call from List1 below highlighted three columns Delivery Qty, Delivery Date & Balance Qty values in List2 columns.

So if user enter Data in List1 for these three columns it will get updated in List2. Is this possible with OOTB functionality. Please advice.

[image]

Comment: You can do this OOTP with Sharepoint designer, Assuming both lists have same columns.

It means, you want to copy 3 columns from list1 to list2, then those 3 columns should be present in both the lists.

Let me know if any help is required on that.

Comment: Devang - Sorry this already done. Thanks for your help and comment.